# Quote markdown can interfere MathJax, is it a bug or a feature?

Tags: bug, mathjax, markdown

I found that quote markdown sometimes interferes MathJax.

```
> This is an example that shows how quote markdown can interfere MathJax. $ E
> =mc^2$.
```

produces

> This is an example that shows how quote markdown can interfere MathJax. $ E
> > =mc^2$.

Of course it can easily be fixed by removing the leading `>` as follows

```
> This is an example that shows how quote markdown can interfere MathJax. $ E
 =mc^2$.
```

to produce the correct result

> This is an example that shows how quote markdown can interfere MathJax. $ E
>   =mc^2$.

However if someone copy a long passage with a lot of MathJax, paste it and press the quote button (or typing the shortcut `ctrl+q`), there is a chance this problem will occur again in the future. The real case is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/2463047/1).

Should typing `ctrl+q` or pressing the quote button automatically insert `<blockquote>...</blockquote>` instead of some lines prefixed by `>`?

Answer (score 4):

You can it seems quote with

```
<blockquote>
$E=
mc^2$
</blockquote>
```

> $E=
> mc^2$

rather than use the leading `>`  if you want to quote a multi-line mathjax expresion

Comment: Thus pressing `ctrl+q` or pressing the quote button should wrap the text with `blockquote` rather than prefixing every line with `>`. :-)